# Why kakfa topic partition is not receiving messages?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka cluster with 3 brokers and a topic with 8 partitions. 
A producer written in java using spring boot and without custom rule for load balancing. It means it should do round robin.

The issue is that there are some partitions there are not receiving messages into it. I figured it out checking what the 4 consumers are receiving and even they are processing all messages there is a consumer idle all the time because it has received just one message.

What could be the issue?
Kafka version I'm using is 0.10.1.1
Additional note in this case I'm not using replicas for the partitions

Comment: So, you have 8 partitions and 4 consumers(single thread) ?
How many messages are published into that topic ?

Answer (score 1):

> It means it should do round robin.

It will only do round robin, if you have no `keys` in your Kafka messages. Otherwise, the messages are partitioned based on a hash value of the key:

```
hash(key) % number_of_partitions
```

It is not unusal, that this will cause some partitions to not receive any messages at all. Imagine a case, where you are using a key that can only have two different values. In that case, all your data will flow into only two partitions, independent of the number of partitions in your topic.

Comment: thanks @mike, you're right in this point. However, there is no key on the messages.